# How can I build pyquery for pypy?

Tags: python, lxml, pypy, pyquery

I'm trying to use pyquery with pypy but it depends on lxml2, which won't build under pypy. I know there's a lxml2 build that is meant to be used with pypy but I don't know how to make pyquery use that instead of the usual one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pypy 5.0 and lxml 3.6 are designed to work well with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `lxml`. [From pyquery package docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery):

```
>>> from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> import urllib
>>> d = pq("<html></html>")
>>> d = pq(etree.fromstring("<html></html>"))
>>> d = pq(url=your_url)
>>> d = pq(url=your_url,
...        opener=lambda url, **kw: urlopen(url).read())
>>> d = pq(filename=path_to_html_file)
```

**UPDATE:**

You need to use a PyPy-friendly version of `lxml`. Fortunately, it already exists and is named `lxml-cffi`. To use it in your pyquery build, first you should create your own fork of the project: https://github.com/gawel/pyquery.

Then, edit `setup.py` to add the following argument to `setup(...)` call:

```
    dependency_links=[
        'git+https://github.com/amauryfa/lxml@cffi'
    ]
```

Finally, install your package:

`pip install git+https://github.com/YOUR_GITHUB_HANDLE/pyquery.git`

After you get it working, I strongly recommend you to push your fork and try to communicate with the responsible for [this website](http://packages.pypy.org/) to include a note pointing to your fork in the `pyquery` entry.

Comment: How do you build it with lxml? I still have the same problem.

Comment: You need to fork `pyquery` and replace the dependency of `lxml` with `lxml-cffi`. https://github.com/amauryfa/lxml/

Comment: If you type the instructions into an answer I'll accept it.